# Mysql select. Only selecting rows where entity != multiple values

Tags: mysql

Hi I was wondering whether someone would be able to help me with a query. I am trying to select from an EAV type table where the value is not multiple values.

Using the example below I am trying to retrieve rows where tag_id != 1 and tag_id != 2. So based on the data I want to return just the row containing contact_id 3

```
Tags Table:

contact_id     tag_id 
  1             1
  1             2
  2             1
  2             4
  3             4
```

The desire result is to return a single row:

```
contact_id -> 3
```

I have tried the following queries which don't return what I am looking for so are obviously are not correct:

```
select `contact_id` from `contact_tags` where tag_id !=1 and tag_id != 2

select `contact_id` from `contact_tags` where tag_id NOT IN(1,2)
```

Any help on this. Or just a pointer in the right direction would be great.

Comment: This is **not** an EAV model. This would be more appropriately called a mapping table.

Comment: Can you display desirable result please?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Thanks for letting me know. I'm just a part time programmer so didn't know the correct term for this kind of table

Comment: What about the row where tag_id=4??

Comment: @Mihai Sorry I'm not sure I made it totally clear. I am trying to return only contacts who do not have both tag_id 1 and 2. So in the example table that would just be contact_id 3

Comment: @PaulAtkins *return only contacts who do not have both tag_id 1 and 2* -- if that's the case `contact_id = 2` should be included since it only match to one element. Maybe you mean atleast one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this is what you want

```
select contact_id 
from contact_tags 
where contact_id not in (
    select contact_id from contact_tags where tag_id in (1,2)
) tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` in which the statement inside selects all records where it has tags of `1` or `2`.

```
SELECT  contact_id
FROM    contact_tags a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    contact_tags b
            WHERE   tag_id IN (1, 2) AND
                    a.contact_id = b.contact_id
        )
GROUP   BY contact_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b11/5)

Another alternative is to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.contact_id
FROM    contact_tags a
        LEFT JOIN contact_tags b
          ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id AND
              b.tag_id IN (1, 2)
WHERE   b.contact_id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b11/13)

Answer (score 0):

Stealing from @491243 fiddle here is a modification which returns contacts_id which lack both tags_id

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2b11/19